# Optimize loading of remote images in Adobe AIR

Tags: image, actionscript-3, air, arrays

I've spent hours googling and referenced all the livedocs but can find no objective comparison between the 2 following methods to load images

1 Loader with loaderContext=ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD
as per this example
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2931

and
2 URLLoader using URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY and Loader.loadBytes

Could anyone possibly shed some insight as to which is better-quicker?

Comment: When in doubt write a test, make 1000 of each and record time before and after.  Test on the type of device you expect the application to run on.

Answer (score 0):

`Loader` is in a way an extension of `URLLoader`. If all u need is a binary for storage then use `URLLoader`. However, if binary needs to be decoded, you'd be better off using `Loader`, because you will need it anyway, even if you use the `URLLoader` to load the binary. With policy of `ON_LOAD` the decoding will take place in another thread.